# Read 9 digit integer from serial

Tags: arduino

I am preparing an Arduino project. I want to take a student number, which is 9 digits such as 140201004, and I want to use it as ID. But when I write to the serial monitor it is converted to 19500.

What am I doing wrong?

```cpp
int readnumber(void) {
  int num = 0;
  boolean validnum = false;

  while (1) {
    while (! Serial.available());
    char c = Serial.read();
    if (isdigit(c)) {
      num *= 10;
      num += c - '0';
      validnum = true;
    } else if (validnum) {
      return num;
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);
  if(Serial.available()>0) {
    data=Serial.read();
    if(data=='1') { 
       Serial.print("Enrolling ID #");
       int id = readnumber();
       Serial.println(id);
       getFingerprintEnroll(id);      
    }
    if(data=='4') {
       getFingerprintID();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` is a 16-bit signed integer and the numbers can go from `−32,768` to `32,767`.
Your number `140,201,004` is obviously too big.

In binary `140,201,004` is `00001000 01011011 01001100 00101100`, and if you only take the lower 16 bits, you get `01001100 00101100` which is `19,500` in decimal as you have seen.

To be able to store that number, you need a 32-bit integer. And since you don't need negative numbers it should be unsigned.

You should replace

```cpp
int num = 0;
```

with

```cpp
unsigned long num = 0;
```

or

```cpp
uint32_t num = 0;
```

Also replace the return type of the function.